# How to make all k8s nodes read/wrote from/to one shared storage on Google Compute Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have 20 VM Instance on GCE with kubernetes self install (using the following https://medium.com/edureka/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-5cd1f770c9e4).

I want all the pod was created on pods node read/write files from one shared storage.

Example:

```
pod1 on node1 write file to /some/shared/directory/pod1file.txt
pod12 on node12 read the file /some/shared/directory/pod1file.txt
...
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do would be to go to kubernetes volumes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes), and see from the available storage options which supports shared volumes; like `gluster` or `ceph`.

As coderanger is mentioning, you can also use `nfs`, and go for `Filestore`. The drawback is the price here. `Filestore` is not cheap, to not say it is expensive. And the minimum storage to get is 1TB, I think, so if you need say 100GB storage, not possible. Now, that's the ONLY storage service you can use on `GCP`, as Managed Service.

If not `Filestore` you are left with creating your own `gluster`, for example, or any other shared storage on GCE, and mount it into your pods.

Answer (score 2):

Google offers Cloud Filestore which is hosted NFS. You can then use that with your pods.